# Fill in empty blocks for a calendar month

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, dayjs

I am currently able to fetch the given days of the current month as well as previous and future months using JS. What I would like to achieve, is if say December starts on a Tuesday I would like to pass in empty objects for Sunday and Monday. December also ends on a Thursday, so I would like to pass in empty objects for Friday and Saturday.

The code I am currently using to fetch each calendar month and display them is as follows:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.scss";
import dayjs from "dayjs";

export default function App() {
  const [dates, setDates] = useState(null);
  const [inc, setIncrement] = useState(0);

  const getDaysArray = async (firstDay, lastDay) => {
    let dates = [];

    while (firstDay <= lastDay) {
      dates.push(firstDay);
      firstDay = dayjs(firstDay).add(1, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    }

    return dates;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const getInitial = async () => {
      const firstDay = dayjs().startOf("month").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      const lastDay = dayjs(firstDay).endOf("month").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      const dates = await getDaysArray(firstDay, lastDay);
      setDates(dates);
    };
    getInitial();
  }, []);

  const fetchMonth = async (inc) => {
    setIncrement(inc);
    const firstDay = dayjs()
      .subtract(inc, "months")
      .startOf("month")
      .format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    const lastDay = dayjs(firstDay).endOf("month").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    const dates = await getDaysArray(firstDay, lastDay);
    setDates(dates);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => fetchMonth(inc + 1)}>DECREMENT</button>
      <button onClick={() => fetchMonth(inc - 1)}>INCREMENT</button>
      <div className="cal">
        <div className="cal-div1"></div>
        <div className="cal-div2 "></div>
        <div className="cal-div3 cal-cir-hov"></div>
        <div className="cal-div4"> SUN </div>
        <div className="cal-div5"> MON </div>
        <div className="cal-div6"> TUE </div>
        <div className="cal-div7"> WED </div>
        <div className="cal-div8"> THU </div>
        <div className="cal-div9"> FRI </div>
        <div className="cal-div10"> SAT </div>
        {dates &&
          dates.map((r, i) => {
            return (
              <div style={{ color: "#565254" }} key={i} className="cal-cir-hov">
                {r}
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

the reason I am attempting to do so is due to the grid I have created. As it stands now, every month starts at sunday and I am not successfully pairing the correct days of the month with the days on the calendar. For example december starts on a tuesday, yet my styling shows it starts on a sunday any help would be greatly appreciated. the console logs currently show the days each month should start and end on.

I am unsure of how to push empty strings into my array for the days that should be empty on my calendar.

attached is a code pen for debugging : https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-cartwright-dm8go?file=/src/App.js:0-2006

Comment: Wrap each dayjs in another object which also has the day of week parameter. Before starting each month, add some new object instances with empty dayjs for those days which are empty in your grid. The array of new objects would be the data model for your Grid.

Comment: could you by chance show me what you mean, I think I understand what you are saying but I'm not positive

Comment: It was simpler than what i said. You can just add null objects for the preceding empty days of a month. You can see the updated code and output on your sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-wu-86y8s

Comment: ahh i see what you mean now.  this is perfect thank you so much

Comment: @AbbasSabeti Looks like a nice fix, I think it would fit well as an answer.